# Intermittant DriveWriteVolume rateMax exception

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been struggling with this error since about a week before DriveApp was released. I have a section of code that fails intermittantly with the error:

> Service invoked too many times in a short time: driveWriteVolume rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.

Here is the code in question:

```
for(var a = 0; a<attachments.length; a++){

   if(a > 0){
     child = "." + (a + 1) + " ";
   }
   else{
     child = ".1 ";
   }

   var parent = (m + 1);
   Utilities.sleep(5000);
   var file = attachmentFolder.createFile(attachments[a]);//This is the line that causes the error.
   Utilities.sleep(1000);
   file.rename(parent + child + attachments[a].getName());

}
```

I started with 1000ms, then gradually worked up to 5000 and it still throws the error every ~200 iterations. This is using DocsList.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in a script I'm working on.

The problem arises when I loop through the attachments to the message and attempt to save them too.  If I skip the attachments, I don't have a problem, even with the same number of total file creations and the same sleep time between them.  This is the code I'm using.  `newFolder.createFile(pdfBlob)` does not cause a problem.  `newFolder.createFile(attachmentBlob)` does.

```
        // Create the message PDF inside the new folder
        var htmlBodyFile = newFolder.createFile('body.html', messageBody, "text/html");
        var pdfBlob = htmlBodyFile.getAs('application/pdf');
        pdfBlob.setName(newFolderName + ".pdf");
        newFolder.createFile(pdfBlob);
        Utilities.sleep(sleepTime);  // wait after creating something on the drive.
        htmlBodyFile.setTrashed(true);


        // Save attachments
        Logger.log("Saving Attachments");
        for(var i = 0; i < messageAttachments.length; i++) {
          Logger.log("Saving Attachment " + i);
          var attachmentBlob = messageAttachments[i].copyBlob();
          newFolder.createFile(attachmentBlob);
          Utilities.sleep(sleepTime);  // wait after creating something on the drive.
        } // each attachment
```